# Find Number Equal to the sum of factorial of each of its digits eg:145

Tags: java

Find Number Equal to the sum of factorial of each of its digits eg:145
From 1 to 200
I tried this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0, x = 0, temp, temp1, digit = 0, factorial = 1, sum = 0;
    System.out.println("Special Numbers from 1 to 10,000 -:");
    for (i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
        temp = i;
        temp1 = i;
        while (temp > 0) {
            digit = temp % 10;
            factorial = 1;
            for (x = 1; x <= digit; x++) {
                factorial *= x;//factorial of digit
            }
            sum += factorial;//sum of factorial of a all the digits of the number
            temp = temp / 10;
        }
        if (sum == temp1) {
            System.out.println(temp1);
        }
    }
}
```

So if i put i=145 it works but othervise i get the wrong output.

Comment: "i get the wrong output" What is the wrong output? What is the *right* output?

Comment: I'm going to guess you are having problems because 145! is much, much to big to store in an `int`.

Comment: Wrong is only "1" appears

Comment: Not factorial of 145 but sum of factorial of digits of 145 like

Comment: Your code is riddled and unstructured. You should try to structure your code before posting, that way it is easier to follow your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to make sum 0, so you only get the correct result for the first number you try. The line `sum = 0;` should go before `while(temp>0){`.

Comment: Thanx a lot you are right was stuck on this annoying bug for hours

Comment: @RayyanMerchant Glad I could help. You can avoid these mistakes by declaring variables inside loops. It would be better to do `int sum = 0;` inside the while loop.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion it is duly noted

Answer (score 1):

Your `sum` variable is declared outside the for block.

Each time you calculate a factorial sum get added to the previous sum and hence `1! + 4! + 5!` will never be `145` in this case.

Try initializing it inside the loop to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `sum` inside the `for` loop.

```
for(i=1;i<=200;i++){
    sum = 0; //<--include this
    temp = i;
    temp1 = i;
    while(temp>0){
        digit = temp%10;
        factorial =1;
        for(x = 1;x<=digit;x++){
            factorial*=x;//factorial of digit
        }
        sum+=factorial; //sum of factorial
        temp = temp/10;
    }
    if(sum == temp1){
        System.out.println(temp1);
    }
}
```